# how to identify duplicate entries in a form using spring mvc 3.0 and jquery.validate.js plugin

Tags: jquery, spring, validation, spring-mvc, jquery-validate

i want to identify duplicate entries of user name (phone,email ...etc) by using jquery.validate.js plugin how can i do this, i tried in this way (I new to ajax and jquery pleas help) ..

```
function submitForm() {

    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            remote: {
                url: "../user/findUser.action",
                type: "get",
                data: userName,

                success: function(userName){
                 alert("it is new user name");
                },
                error: function(e){
                  alert("User Name Already Present");
               }

                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        username: {
            required: "Enter a username"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

but itś not hitting to controller

this is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/catalogue/getTitle", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=*/*")
    public @ResponseBody List<User> getTitleList(@RequestParam("term") String query) {
        return getMatchTitle(query);
    }
    public List<User> getMatchTitle(String query) {
        List<User> matched = userService.getUserList(query);

        if(matched == true)
        {
            return false ;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

i think it´s not proper coding sorry for that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your requestMapping value says `"/catalogue/getTitle"` whereas your jquery ajax call says `"/user/findUser.action"`. Thats why its not reaching controller.